# EntityManager became NULL after a while (about 10m)

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0

in my JavaEE 6 application (JBoss 6.0.0.Final) I have a class hierarchy outlined like this

```
@Stateful public class UserFacade
{
  @Inject @MyRepository
  private EntityManager em;
}

@Stateful public class UserBl
{
  @EJB private UserFacade fUser;
}

public class MyServlet
{
  @EJB private UserBl blUser;
}
```

The servlet is used during a login process and it works fine. But if the servlet is called from the same browser after an inactivity period of about 10 minutes, the `EntityManager em` in `UserBl` became `NULL` (checked this explicitly before using it).

In a other application (JBoss 5.1.0.GA) I've had a similar issued and solved it by explicitly checking for `NULL` and looking up the `EntitiyManager` from the context in that case.

I'm wondering if there is a fundamental design flaw or if I missed something. In this scenario `@Stateless` Beans are possible, too. But in my understanding this should also work with `@Stateful` Beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I recall, injection of stateful beans has been problematic (at least in JavaEE 5). It might be a passivation-activation issue.

But you don't really need stateful beans here - the `EntityManager` is per-transaction (by default; you can set it to extended which allows it span multiple requests) and a stateless bean is the proper way to go.